# How does CtMethod affects classloading? CtMethod.insertBefore() is ineffective

Tags: reflection, classloader, bytecode, instrumentation, javassist

Please read along. I have a `Lion` class that has a method `stayLion`.

```
public class Lion {
    //class Variables and methods
    public void stayLion(String temp,int temp2,double temp3, boolean temp4,Food food) throws InterruptedException {
    //method Body
    }
}
```

The method takes in a `Food` instance as one of its parameter. Food class has `cook` method

```
public class Food{
    public void cook(){
    }
}
```

I am trying to instrument both these methods, `stayLion` and `cook`. **The transform method is called for every class that is loaded by JVM.**(Interesed to know, where and who calls it. Correct me if I am wrong) If classname matches with my desired list of classnames, I extract the list of methods, and verify the methodName and its parameter, I find the CtMethod instance for the method I wish to instrument (stayLion and cook).

```
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, final  String className, Class classBeingRedefined,  ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
    //verifying className(fully qualified), if same then,
    ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass ctClass = classPool.getCtClass(className.replace("/","."));
    CtMethod[] methods = ctClass.getDeclaredMethods();

    for (CtMethod method : methods) {
        //verifying method (name and parameter)
        method.insertBefore( //some code );
    }
}
```

However, in the process of verifying parameters for `stayLion`, the `Food` class gets loaded and **transform method is not called**, (I don't know the reason for this. The class loader is same. Why is transform method not called for Food class as it gets loaded?). To overcome this, I explicitly call `transform` method for `Food` class (in general, I call `transform` method everytime a class whose method I wish to instrument is in the parameter list of any other method I also wish to instrument).

```
transform(loader,"com/here/debugHelper/Food",null,protectionDomain,null);
```

But this explicit calling of transform method is ineffective. To be precise,

```
ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
CtClass ctClass = classPool.getCtClass(className.replace("/","."));
CtMethod[] methods = ctClass.getDeclaredMethods();
```

Till here, `methods` contains list of all methods of Food class. After verifying `cook` method with no parameter

```
for (CtMethod method : methods) {
    //verifying method (name and parameter)
    method.insertBefore( //some code );
}
```

But at this point, `method.insertBefore()` is ineffective and is not adding any code to the desired method.

Answer (score 0):

The `transform` method is invoked by the JVM during class loading or redefinition. It does not make much sense for you to call the method directly unless you are testing.

If you are loading a class during a code manipulation, no class being loaded will be transformed. This is to avoid circularities in your instrumentation where instrumenting `A`loads `B` and instrumenting `B` loads `A`. If you attempt to load the instrumented class itself, this will result in a `ClassCircularityError`.

I assume that when you instrument `Lion`, you are loading `Food` when processing the parameters. By using Javassist, you normally avoid this as Javassist loads class files directly but I figure that you are referencing the `Lion` class as a constant somewhere and therefore load it somwhere in your transformer.

Comment: I understand that in the process of instrumenting code, if I call `transform`, there lies a risk of infinite loop. I am having a proper base case to avoid that.
I am making an instance of `Lion` class in main method. It loads and respective methods get instrumented. However, just after that,  I am also making instance of `Food` class, which was also expected to go through same route and get instrumented. It however doesn't happen, because it has been loaded in the process of instrumenting `Lion`. How can I avoid this situation?? 
Thanks for help

Comment: You can apply a class file transformer on loaded classes using the `Instrumentation::retransformClasses` method. You have to enable this feature in the agent's manifest. Make sure that you do not change the signature of the class when retransforming.

Comment: I am not sure where and how to  call this `retransformClasses` method from.
Alternatively, I have maintained a map that corresponds a classname to classnames of classes that are parameter of methods desired to get instrumented, and they themselves are in the desired list of to-be-instrumented-classes. This way, when I enter `transform` method for `Lion`, I see the map, find `Food` class as one of its dependent, and try to call `transform` method at this point.

Comment: You would call the method from your agent after installing the class file transformer with the boolean `canRetransform` parameter set to true.

Comment: `public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) throws UnmodifiableClassException {
  System.out.println("Starting  premain.........");


  ConfigObj configObj = getConfig(agentArgs);


  inst.addTransformer(new DurationTransformer2(configObj),true);

  inst.retransformClasses(configObj.getClasses());

  System.out.println("Ending premain!\n");
 }`

Comment: `configObj` is a helper class that has all the class names, method names etc in appropriate containers that are to be instrumented. I use that in `transform` method. `configObj.getClasses` returns the list of `Class` objects of all the classes in my list. I have made changes in manifest file. However, after all of this. There is no instrumentation happening. Am I missing out anything here?

Comment: Do you catch throwable in your transformer? If an error is happening, it will be supressed.